# Using .when() with .agg()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have some data which I am taking the max of like this:

```
t = (
    spark.table('schema.t1')
    .where(F.col('yyyy_mm_dd').between('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'))
    .select('id', 'is_enabled')
    .groupby('id')
    .agg(
        sf.max('is_enabled').alias('is_enabled')
    )
)
```

The data in `is_enabled` is either 1/0 and I would like to replace it with 'true' and 'false' respectively.

I have tried this:

```
t = (
    spark.table('schema.t1')
    .where(F.col('yyyy_mm_dd').between('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'))
    .select('id', 'is_enabled')
    .groupby('id')
    .agg(
        sf.max('is_enabled').alias('is_enabled')
    )
    .when(sf.col('is_enabled') == 0, 'false')
    .otherwise('true')
)
```

But I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'when'

I have also tried:

```
t = (
    spark.table('schema.t1')
    .where(F.col('yyyy_mm_dd').between('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'))
    .select('id', 'is_enabled')
    .groupby('id')
    .agg(
        sf.max('is_enabled').alias('is_enabled')
    )
)

t = (
    t
    .when(sf.col('is_enabled') == 0, 'false')
    .otherwise('true')
)
```

And got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `withColumn` to change the column, and put the `when` statement inside the `withColumn`:

```
t = (
    spark.table('schema.t1')
    .where(F.col('yyyy_mm_dd').between('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'))
    .select('id', 'is_enabled')
    .groupby('id')
    .agg(
        sf.max('is_enabled').alias('is_enabled')
    )
    .withColumn(
        'is_enabled', 
        sf.when(sf.col('is_enabled') == 0, 'false').otherwise('true')
    )
)
```

Or you can put the `when` statement inside `agg`:

```
t = (
    spark.table('schema.t1')
    .where(F.col('yyyy_mm_dd').between('2020-01-01', '2021-01-01'))
    .select('id', 'is_enabled')
    .groupby('id')
    .agg(
        sf.when(sf.max('is_enabled') == 0, 'false')
          .otherwise('true').alias('is_enabled')
    )
)
```